# What does semicolon do in this Excel function?

Tags: excel

I uasually work in R or Stata, but I have come across an excel spreadsheet that I need to convert into an R script.

Most of it is pretty straight forward, but I am struggling with understanding what the below  cell function does. It is especially the last part with `2;B39-1;L39` that I dont understand.

My Excel version is European, so as far as I have read that means the semicolon could be a comma in non-European versions of Excel.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
=M39/FINV((1-E39/100)/2;B39-1;L39)

M39 = 28  
E39 = 95  
B39 = 14  
L39 = 26
```

The result of the function is 11.4

Comment: On a computer that uses a semi-colon as the system list separator, the semi-colon separates the parameters (aka arguments). On a computer that uses a comma as the system list separator, these semi-colons need to be changed to commas.

Comment: `;` is argument separator. [FINV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/finv-function-4d46c97c-c368-4852-bc15-41e8e31140b1) is a function requiring 3 arguments. So `(1-E39/100)/2` is the *Probability*, `B39-1` is the *Deg_freedom1* and `L39` is the *Deg_freedom2*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @L42. Please make an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, `;` semi-colon is an argument separator. [FINV](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/finv-function-4d46c97c-c368-4852-bc15-41e8e31140b1) is a function requiring three(3) arguments with the following syntax:

> FINV(*probability*,*deg_freedom1*,*deg_freedom2*)

So in your formula:

- *Probability* is `(1-E39/100)/2`
- *Deg_freedom1* is `B39-1`
- *Deg_freedom2* is `L39`

Take note though that there are *regional differences* in Excel in terms of what default separator is being used (what you hinted in your question) which is greatly explained in this [*Excel Tip*](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/understanding-regional-differences-in-excel/1/).

> ...there are also many regional differences when it comes to certain tasks in Excel, including **separating arguments**, writing numbers, and function names.

Comment: Thank you L42.   For anyone else using R and in a similar situation as mine. The R equivalent to the Excel function FINV is `df(x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)`. Note that default settings is  log =TRUE which does not give the result as default FINV.